# DPI settings are not restored after RDP session

Tags: windows-8.1, dpi

My original DPI setting - 125% (medium).

When I RDP to my home PC from work, then disconnect (close) RDP, come back home and login locally - DPI settings are not restored to the original setting (125%), it remains at 100% (default). Display properties shows correct DPI setting.

I have to log-off and log back in order to see correct DPI. This is inconvenient because I need to restart all my programs.

Please advise on the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain it's still the same in Win 8.1, but in previous OSes, the trick is to enable Smart Sizing, otherwise your remote session changes the actual screen resolution of the remote machine.

To use Smart Sizing in Windows XP or Windows 7 you need to edit your .rdp files with notepad and type in the following line:

`smart sizing:i:1`